# Не работает Тг-бот через PuTTy

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, развертывание, putty

Есть бот, которого деплоил через PuTTy. Уже неоднократно вносил в него изменения через FileZilla. Но сегодня потерпел фиаско: после очередной загрузки и запуска бота (успешного) он не работает и примерно спустя 10 секунд PuTTy пишет "Killed". В чём может быть проблема?
P.s. локально всё работает замечательно

Comment: Читайте dmesg .

Comment: Но скорее всего что-то внутри бота стремительно сжирает всю память